# Cannot pass chan implementation to method requiring chan interface

Tags: go

I have an interface X and an implementation of X called Y.

The problem is that I have a method which receives chan X as a parameter, but when I pass the variable channel, which is of type Y, I get the error "Cannot use 'channel' (type chan Y) as type chan X".

I have ensured that Y does indeed implement all of X's methods but so I'm unsure of how to solve this problem. Any help on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "solve" this problem in that way, a `chan Y` cannot be used in place of a `chan X`, regardless of the relationship between `X` and `Y`.

You need to rework your code so that, if a function requires you to give it a `chan X`, you're giving it a `chan X`.

If `X` is an interface, and `Y` fulfills that interface, you can send pointers to `Y` over a `chan X`, but that doesn't make a `chan Y` usable as a `chan X`. Doing so would completely break the contract of a `func(chan X)`. Imagine if that function, accepting a `chan X`, could receive a `chan Y`. Now internally the function expects to be able to send a `Z`, which also implements the `X` interface, over that same channel, but can't, because instead of holding the `chan X` it requires, you've given it the wrong channel type.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So does this mean that interfaces cannot be used in a polymorphic way in channels?

Comment: Yes, they certainly can, if a channel takes an interface type, you can pass a pointer to anything that implements that interface over the channel.

Comment: Ah yes I think I understand you now! The channel of type chan Y cannot send and receive everything that a chan Y could so it cant be used

Comment: "If X is an interface, and Y fulfills that interface, you can send pointers to Y over a chan X" - if `Y` fulfills that interface, you can send `Y`, it doesn't have to be a pointer unless only `*Y` fulfills the interface.